# writing a Rake task for renaming a field name in a table in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I am very new to rails application. I need to change the column name of a table .. 
SO i browsed thru some sites and as thy mentioned i thought of writing migration file ..

```
  class RenameNameToFirstnameInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      rename_column 'users', 'name', 'first_name'
    end

    def self.down
        rename_column 'users', 'first_name', 'name'
    end
 end
```

How to save this file and where ??

applicationname/db/migrate/

In what name i can save this ??
As far now i have seen many files there but all those have prefix of some big_number

And after saving this , how do i test it in my local??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is:

Rails3

`rails generate migration RenameNameToFirstnameInUsers`

Rails2

`script/generate migration RenameNameToFirstnameInUsers`

And then edit the created migration file, and migrate your db as normal.

Comment: "migrate your db as normal" = run "rake db:migrate"

Comment: Easiest and recommended since file name and classname must match, i.e. class name should be the result of `(file name minus the migration number).classify`

Comment: i did in the same way as u said , and the column name changed as well . But it blocks some of the links in my applications??

Comment: Is it possible to write a hash in model and comparing the  key and its value in the view ??

Comment: blocks some of the links your in applications such as <%= u.name %> no longer works? You will either need to change everything that requests name on the user model to be first_name.  or else you could add a virtual attribute to your model def name \n first_name \n end    (replace \n with new lines)